# Uppercase in regex

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext2

I don't know anything about regex,but I need to tranform a variable ($name) to uppercase.
Does anybody know how to do it ?

Also, what is a good website for learning regex?

Comment: Are you doing the whole string to uppercase? if so just "string".toUpperCase() (if JS) - what language are you using?

Comment: Yes the whole string. I need to use Perl Regular expression syntax [Perl Regex Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

Comment: "I need to use ..." Is this homework or something?

Comment: :) No no, I know the rules :) I'm trying to customize my sublime text 2 editor but I'm not able to do this. I don't understand why I got a -1 by btw...

Comment: You mentioned Perl, but this is really for Sublime Text 2. Are you saying ST2 embeds a Perl interpreter, or does it just implement Perl-like regex? I suspect you can't use Perl code at all.

Comment: Humm, Yes your right I can't use perl syntax at all. I shouldn't have mentioned Perl. It's just about regular expression

Comment: Regular expressions are used to define patterns, so they are not sufficient. You need to means to replace the matched strings, which you surely have. And you also need to replace the matched string conditionally based on the string matched. That requires the ability to define code to be executed to determine the string to use as the replacement string. Does ST2 have that ability? You asked how to transform a variable (by which I presume you mean its value), so I presume there is some programming language available to you (or else you wouldn't have variables), so it may be possible.

Comment: ST2 has the ability to use such regex in the code but I don't know what programming language is available to me. So there are questions I need to ask to ST2 dev team, otherwise I won't be able to understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
s/(\pL+)/\U$1/g
```

The capture parens will find letters, and the `\U` [escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) will apply the `uc` function to the captured text in `$1`. The `/g` modifier will repeat the match throughout the string.

For a more generic regex you can try

```
s/(.*)/\U\1/g
```

...where it matches all characters, and `\1` is the old style capture sequence.

Comment: Seems to be a good idea, but I can't use Perl syntax only regex. I mentioned perl but it is only because sublime text 2 website's mentions it. That is a mistake.

Comment: @Atha Well, that is the regex `s/(\pL+)/\U$1/g`. I have no idea how its implemented in sublime text whatnot. For a more generic regex you can try `s/(.*)/\U\1/g`, where it matches all characters, and `\1` is the old capture sequence.

Comment: Thank you ! I think I will email the sublime dev team to know more about that.

Comment: @Atha Which regex worked for you? Might be good to add to the answer.

Comment: ${s/(.*)/\U\$name/g} Works perfectly fine ! Thank you ! I now have to learn about regex I think :)

Comment: `$name`? Where did that come from?

Comment: It's the name of the variable that is given when creating the file. It's correctly transformed by the regex. I'm missing the first letter of the variable though but I'll find out.

Comment: Well, I see that you use `\$name` instead of `$name`, perhaps that has something to do with it.

Comment: Ok You're right. :) I'm gonna buy a book on regular expression because this seem to be useful and I don't know anything about it...

Comment: Yes, it is a versatile tool to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

TextPad will allow you to perform this opperation.

example:

```
test
```

Find what: ([^ ]*) (.*) Replace with: \U\1\E \2

Result will be:

```
TEST
```

Comment: That's what i'm trying to achieve, but without having to write "Find what" and "Replace with".

Comment: Is there any special reason for not using the "Find what" and "Replace with"?

Comment: When creating a new file, via the "FileTemplate" extension in sublime text 2, I want to replace $name by its uppercase version in `#ifndef $name_H
#define $name_H`. I tried using Find what and Replace with bu it does not work.

Comment: For example, a snippet in sublime text 2 looks like this :    '<content><![CDATA[fprintf(${1:stderr}, "${2:%s}\\n"${2/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:, :\);)/}$3${2/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:\);)/}]]></content>'

Answer (score 0):

do you really need to use a regex? if not have a look at the perl `tr///` operator